# print random row from Google Spreadsheet via php

Tags: php, google-sheets

I would like to create a PHP script that  fetches a few rows from a Google Spreadsheets and display it in html.

```
$authService = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$httpClient = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $authService);
$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($httpClient);
$feed = $gdClient->getSpreadsheetFeed('https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=MY_DOC_KEY');
$currKey = explode('/', $feed->entries[0]->id->text);
$query = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery();
$query->setSpreadsheetKey($this->currKey);
$query->setWorksheetId($this->currWkshtId);
$query->setMinCol(1);
$query->setMaxCol(7);
$query->setMinRow(2);
$feed = $gdClient->getCellFeed($query);
```

However that throws a really ugly error message. What am i doing wrong?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Gdata_App_Exception' with
>   message 'DOMDocument cannot parse XML:
>   DOMDocument::loadXML() Extra content
>   at the end of the document in Entity,
>   line: 23'

Comment: I haven't use Zend_Gdata in my life, but is there any way to see what was actually downloaded from google? Just to make sure it's a proper XML. If it's not, no wonder the Zend's parser can't parse it.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

Why do you want to list the spreadsheets if you already know which spreadsheet you want to read from?

**Long answer:**

I am new to both Zend and Gdata, but tried to run your code and got the same exception.
But after reading the docs (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.spreadsheets.html)  I've tried replacing:

```
$feed = $gdClient->getSpreadsheetFeed('https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=MY_DOC_KEY');
```

with:

```
$feed = $gdClient->getSpreadsheetFeed();
```

and after adding the obvious:

```
foreach($feed as $cellEntry) {
  $row = $cellEntry->cell->getRow();
  $col = $cellEntry->cell->getColumn();  
  $val = $cellEntry->cell->getText();    
  echo "$row, $col = $val\n";      
}
```

I got some data.

Then I understood, these two lines are not needed at all:

```
$feed = $gdClient->getSpreadsheetFeed('https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=MY_DOC_KEY');
$currKey = explode('/', $feed->entries[0]->id->text);
```

So `getSpreadsheetFeed` is useful if you want to list/filter spreadsheets (and then there's no point in suplying the key) and to read the data from the known spreadsheet it's enough to use just the `Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets_CellQuery`.

Now I learned something.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to realize the script via a [Google Spreadsheets class](http://farinspace.com/saving-form-data-to-google-spreadsheets/) that wraps around the Zend Gdata class and makes it a lot easier to use.

Here is the functional code:

```
$ss = new Google_Spreadsheet($user,$password);
$ss->useSpreadsheet("My Spreadsheet");
$ss->useWorksheet('Sheet1');

$rows = $ss->getRows();
if ($rows){
    $data  = returnRandomElement($rows);
    echo 'NonBullshitCollectiveWidget.serverResponse('.json_encode($data).')';
} 
else {
    echo 'NonBullshitCollectiveWidget.serverResponse({"columnName":"Error!"})';
}


function returnRandomElement($array){
    return $array[array_rand($array,1)];
}
```